# XMLDocument going deep

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Right now I have my code similar to this (actually one level deeper).  If the company name is equal to the node of company then create a node list from it (as I need to populate a drop down box with all of the details) ---Not using 3.5 for this project :(

```
XmlNodeList elemList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("company");
foreach (XmlNode node in elemList)
{
    if (node.Attributes[0].Value == company)
    {   
        foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode detail in child.ChildNodes)
            {
                ddlCodes.Items.Add(detail.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not really liking all those `foreach` statements, just wondering if there is a cleaner way. Here is how my xml looks like

```
<companies>
    <company id="company1">
       <code>12</code>
       <detail>detail of 12 code</detail>
    </company>
    <company id="company2">
       <code>15</code>
       <detail>detail of 15 code</detail>
    </company>
</companies>
```

Comment: Can you use .NET 3.5? LINQ to XML makes all of this considerably simpler...

Comment: sorry not usinig 3.5 I wish I was though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `XPath` and the `XPathNavigator` class, it provides you with a query language for XML

Or you could use Linq to XML if you want but that depends on the .net framework you're using.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
[XmlRoot("companies")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement("company")]    
    public company[] companies;
}

public class company
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string id;
    public string code;
    public string detail;
}


XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
Root r = (Root)xml.Deserialize(new StringReader(xmlstr));
```